Angular 17 - Material - Table remove white space in cells / limit row-cell height

The customer wants the white space above and below the text in the cells to be gone, hence border (now red line) almost sticking to the text. Please spare me the artistic discussions, this is what the customers want.
I'm trying to get ride of the white space by removing margin, padding on tr, td. Setting height on tr, td. But none of the seems to do the job, I get stuck with this and a height of 31px although I said it should be 10px.


You can easily override the css variable for the table row height as shown below.
--mat-table-row-item-container-height: 10px;

You can also override the height of headers and footers, if necessary.
--mat-table-header-container-height: 10px;
--mat-table-footer-container-height: 10px;

